# Can't mount cd rom

Tags: server

I am booting the ubuntu server iso file directly. I am not using the usb or cd install so when I try to install I get up to where it says mount cdrom. My computer doesn't have a cdrom by the way so how do I get round this?

Comment: Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: Can you explain the process you are using? are you using loopback in grub or what?